# How to increment List contents in derived classes?

Tags: c#

Given two properties in class `A`:

```
class A
{
    public virtual List<string> BaseStrings{get;}
    public virtual List<string> MyStrings{get;}
}

class B:A
{
    public override List<string> BaseStrings{//baseA.BaseStrings+baseA.MyStrings}
    public override List<string> MyStrings{//?}
}

class C:B
{
    public override List<string> BaseStrings{//baseB.BaseStrings+baseB.MyStrings}
    public override List<string> MyStrings{//?}
}
```

How do I craft the properties so that the `BaseStrings` accumulate in each derived class? I don't want to redeclare that structure in each derived class. I just want to ask for `BaseStrings` for the accumulated base strings.

EDIT: Based on some of the comments, the below classes achieve the goal. What pitfalls will I come across plastering `new` everywhere? It seems as if I cast `D` to any of it's previous forms like `C`, I will get exactly the set of strings I expect to see for a `C`. Yes!

I was hoping there was a way to write this and not be so redundant...

```
public abstract class A
{
    public virtual List<string> BaseStrings { get; } = new List<string>();
    public virtual List<string> MyStrings { get; } = new List<string>();
}

public class B : A
{
   public new List<string> BaseStrings => base.BaseStrings.Concat(base.MyStrings).ToList();

   public new List<string> MyStrings => new List<string>() { "dog", "cat" };
}

public class C : B
{
    public new List<string> BaseStrings => base.BaseStrings.Concat(base.MyStrings).ToList();

    public new List<string> MyStrings => new List<string>() { "Fox", "Hare" };
        
}

public class D : C
{
    public new List<string> BaseStrings => base.BaseStrings.Concat(base.MyStrings).ToList();

    public new List<string> MyStrings =>new List<string>{"Tortise","Fish"};
}
```

Comment: Are you talking *types* or instances? The question is literally unclear. Provide additional information, even example.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: See example. I believe the problem is best described as recursively accumulating a list.

Comment: You override `A.BaseStrings` in `B`, so there's still only one `BaseStrings` per instance - if you want the subclass to hide the base property with a new one, use the `new` keyword: `public new List<string> BaseStrings { get => base.BaseStrings.Concat(base.MyStrings).ToList(); }`

Comment: **Note:** It is not necessary to decorate your post with _"EDIT:"_ as we can see when edits are made.

Comment: Can you describe what are you trying to solve, please? As @MathiasR.Jessen says, when you declare a `var b = new B()`, you only have one property: `b.BaseStrings` (of `B`)...

Comment: All you've overridden is property accessors - you haven't defined any actual lists at all. I would consider rephrasing your question as "I want to do X. I've tried Y (source code) but it doesn't work (error/incorrect result). How do I do X?"

Comment: Do you mean you want to reduce the code duplication of `public override List<string> BaseStrings{ ... }`?

Comment: It _sounds_ like you want each class to have a property that contains only it's strings, and a separate property that gives you it's strings plus it's parents' strings (recursively). Is that right?

Comment: @DStanley Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

When aggregating values, don't use lists, as creating a new list for every sub class creates an extra useless iteration and allocation. Instead for purposes of aggregation, use `IEnumerable<T>`.

I think what you want is something like so:

```
class A
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetStrings() {
        yield return "Base String A";
        yield return "Base String B";
    }
}

class B:A
{
    public override IEnumerable<string> GetStrings() {
        foreach (string b in base.GetStrings())
            yield return b;
        yield return "My String C";
        yield return "My String D";
    }
}

class C:B
{
    public override IEnumerable<string> GetStrings() {
        foreach (string b in base.GetStrings())
            yield return b;
        yield return "My String E";
        yield return "My String F";
    }
}
```

If you really insist on using `List` properties, you can do that while still aggregating with `IEnumerable`, the below would work. Just remember that since you make `MyStrings` `virtual`, any implementation that overrides that now takes full ownership and potentially erases all previously held values in any sub classes. So `C`'s overrid of `MyStrings` can completely wipe out all of `B`'s held `MyStrings` values. this is why I would always prefer the first solution provided with `IEnumerable`s all the way.

```
class A
{
    public virtual List<string> BaseStrings { get; }
    public virtual List<string> MyStrings { get; }
    
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetStrings() {
        foreach (string b in BaseStrings)
            yield return b;
        foreach (string m in MyStrings)
            yield return m;
    }
}

class B:A
{
    public override List<string> MyStrings {//?}
}

class C:B
{
    public override List<string> MyStrings {//?}
}
```

Now any time you want to grab all the `string`s, just use `item.GetStrings()`

Answer (score 0):

> [I] want each class to have a property that contains only it's strings, and a separate property that gives [me] it's strings plus it's parents' strings (recursively)

I don't think inheritance is the right way to do this - it sounds like you want *encapsulation* (a C *has a* B, which *has a* A).  With inheritance, you have *one instance* that you can treat as either an `A`, a `B`, or a `C`. Different instances will not share the lists with each other.

That said, just for fun, you *could* do it by using  *new* properties (not overridden) for each type:

```
class A
{
    public List<string> BaseStrings { 
        get {
            return this.MyStrings.ToList();
        }
    }
    public List<string> MyStrings{get; set;}
}

class B:A
{
    public new List<string> BaseStrings {
        get {
            return base.BaseStrings.Concat(this.MyStrings).ToList();
        }
    }
    public new List<string> MyStrings{get; set;}
}

class C:B
{
    public new List<string> BaseStrings { 
        get {
            return base.BaseStrings.Concat(this.MyStrings).ToList();
        }
    }
    public new List<string> MyStrings{get; set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
C c = new C();
B b = c;
A a = c;

c.MyStrings = new List<string> {"C"};
b.MyStrings = new List<string> {"B"};
a.MyStrings = new List<string> {"A"};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a.MyStrings));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a.BaseStrings));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b.MyStrings));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b.BaseStrings));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", c.MyStrings));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", c.BaseStrings));
```

Output:

```
A
A
B
A, B
C
A, B, C
```

Comment: Why did you preface your response with "just for fun"?

Comment: If I'm mistaken, please correct. I thought that whenever a `virtual`  is overridden with `override` the `base.` keyword becomes available to access the base implementation?

Comment: Correct, but when you override, the override is used for _any object of that type_. So there's no way to set the list for "A" on an object of type "C". With `new`, each type has it's _own_ property, so you can access them independently by casting.

Comment: I updated my post with a snippet, much like what you posted here. I would guess you said "just for fun" in that way because you are skeptical of using `new`.

Comment: I said "just for fun" because it's a weird way of implementing nested data structures. I'd suggest using the same type and just having one instance contain another, then getting the data recursively.

Comment: In other words, if you create a `C` there's only _one_ object - there's not a `C` and a `B` and an `A`. using `new` allow each type to have it's own list property, but technically it's three different properties on the same object.

Comment: I understand that entirely. It just gets weird I can cast `C` to `B` and I now have a `B` to work with. So is that original object two different things? Well, yes, so long as it's guaranteed `C` inherits from `B`  I can treat B as if it was never ever C all day long but actually wait no it still is just one object...

Comment: No - you have one object that's a `C` _and_ a `B`. If you override the property you're _always_ using the "`C`" property even if you cast it to a `B`. That's why `new` gives you _different_ properties with the same name.